# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' Firebase&Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add Firebase-database to the my Android application and I have got error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.8.0.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

build.gradle app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lukasz.ogloszenia"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-                    core:3.0.2'

        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

change this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
```

to this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
```

All google play services and firebase dependencies need to have the same version number.

This changes starting from version number 15:

> Each Maven dependency matching com.google.android.gms:play-services-* and com.google.firebase:firebase-* is no longer required to have the same version number in order to work correctly at build time and at run time.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html